# How to Update a Column in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, sql, query

How to make an "Update" query in Magento 1.9? I have no Idea how to do it.
I added "filtered" column in **catalog_product_entity** table.

I have the product I.D and here's my Query.

```
 $productId = '9';
 $data  = array('filtered'=>0);
 $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId)->addData($data);
 $model->setId($productId)->save();
```

And this is the query what i want to achieved.

```
"UPDATE catalog_product_entity SET filtered = 1 WHERE entity_id = 9".
```

**Note**: The column "filtered" is added manually using "**ALTER TABLE**" in **catalog_product_entity**.

Comment: Filtered is an text attribute or multiselect or select?

Comment: "Filtered" is a column, I added manually the filtered column in catalog_product_entity.

Answer (score 3):

Try following way

```
$productId = 9;
$saveData = array('custom_col' => 1);
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$where = $write->quoteInto('product_id = ?', $productId);
$write->update('custom_table', $saveData, $where);
```

Comment: Its not working :(

Comment: Which table you want to save? This code should work.

Comment: Sorry I missed spelled the table name. :) It's working.

Comment: Great. Accept this answer it will help other too.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code:**

```
$query =  "UPDATE `catalog_product_entity` SET `filtered` = '1' WHERE `catalog_product_entity`.`entity_id` = 9";

$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$writeConnection->query($query);
$writeConnection->closeConnection();
```